# Alfresco Community 4.2 PostgreSQL

Tags: alfresco

I don't understand on how to access to the bundled database. Do I need to go to a certain url to open an interface and log in?  Or is it from cmd?
Must I do the configuration first, assited in alfresco community help page??

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to access the bundled PostGreSQL database? For almost everything you'd want to do with Alfresco, you'd do that via the Alfresco user interfaces and APIs, you almost never need to touch the underlying RDBMS directly

Comment: I want to view their table structures and find a way to do backup. I'm using Windows 7 at the moment.

Comment: Did you try the [Alfresco Backup and Restore wiki page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Backup_and_Restore)? That covers some of it? Also, because Alfresco stores some bits in the RDBMS, and some bits in the Content Store location, a pure-RDBMS backup will never work...

Comment: Owh, really? Thanks for the link. But its still possible if i want to do simple query like select and insert through it?

Comment: What do you think you're going to be inserting or selecting? It is possible to query or add nodes/users/etc in the underlying RDBMS used by Alfresco, but that's very much a super-expert thing, and not something a beginner should be trying as you'll most likely get it wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Alfresco is installed on your local desktop, you should be able to easily connect with [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/). This you can download separately, or find in the Alfresco bundle, under the postgresql directory.
If Alfresco is installed on a remote server, then you will need to expose the Posgresql port, which 5432 is the default, through any firewalls that may exist. Then you will need to configure [Postgresql to allow remote connection](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html)s.

Comment: I have the folder pgadmin III in the postgresql, which file should I click? I'm sorry for asking such questions..

Comment: And alfresco is installed in my  laptop.